# Put Special words and symbols into an element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text that combine persian language , html elements and English words. I want Engilsh Words and other symbols like( <> ) that they are inside paragraph not other element(like pre) placed into span tag. How do i this with jquery?

before:

```
 در این قسمت تمرکز ما بر LINQ to Objects است که در پرس و جوی مجموعه ای از اشیاء در کد شما که رابط IEnumerable<T> را پیاده سازی می کنند مورد استفاده<imge src="wp/contet/image.png"> قرار می گیرد.
```

after:

```
 در این قسمت تمرکز ما بر <span>LINQ to Objects</span> است که در پرس و جوی مجموعه ای از اشیاء در کد شما که رابط <span>IEnumerable<T></span> را پیاده سازی می کنند مورد استفاده<imge src="wp/contet/image.png"> قرار می گیرد.
```

I Use this code

```
$("p").each(function (){
  var current_element = $(this);
  var old_value = $(this).text();
  old_value = old_value.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
  current_element.html(old_value);});
```

but all image were hidden!

Comment: can you give us an example of your code and what you want the result to be?  this will help to clarify what you're attempting to do.

Comment: post updated. please see

Comment: Suggest you look at doing this at the source

Comment: yes. please see this link http://www.w3-farsi.com/linq-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA/

Comment: I want all english words (not html element) in this text placed into span tag at the source

Comment: I use this code [code] $("p").each(function () 
 {
      var current_element = $(this);
      var old_value = $(this).text();
      old_value = old_value.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g, "<bdo>$1</bdo>");
      current_element.html(old_value);
});[/code] but all image were hidden!

Comment: do you want to wrap the `img` elements within `span` too?

Comment: no , i want just English words wrap into span not html elements